# Adding values to defined byte (DB)

Tags: assembly, byte

I want to do something like this:

```
a db ?
```

Then, I want to add values to it, let's for example say it'd end up like this:

```
a db 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the maximum number of bytes you'll write, yes:

```
.data?
a db 6 dup(?)

.code
mov byte ptr [a],1
mov byte ptr [a+1],2
...
mov byte ptr [a+5],6
```

If you don't know that number (or if it's really large) you'll have to use one of the memory allocation functions provided by the target operating system.

Comment: I don't exactly know the number of bytes I'm going to insert, but it shouldn't be more than 4-5. I thought of doing by saving to a defined memory address like this: `address dw 3000h` `mov si, dw` `mov ds:[si], (value)`. Will it work?

Comment: Using hardcoded addresses is typically a bad idea. There's no guarantee that your program even has permissions to write to memory at the address you pick.

Comment: Then I will use what you have suggested `a db 6 dup(?)`. Thanks a bunch!